# Java : java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Tags: java

**I am storing a double value inside the a HashMap as shown**

```
HashMap listMap = new HashMap();

double mvalue =0.0;

listMap.put("mvalue",mvalue );
```

**Now when i tried to retrieve that value , as shown**

```
mvalue = Double.parseDouble((String) listMap.get("mvalue"));
```

i am getting an error as

**java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.lang.String**

I am confused here ,

**This is my actual HashMap and i am setting the values in it as shown**

```
HashMap listMap = new HashMap();
double mvalue =0.0 ;
List<Bag> bagList = null; 
listMap.put("bagItems",bagList);
listMap.put("mvalue", mvalue);
```

**Could anybody please tell me , how the structure of the HashMap should be ?**

Comment: In addition to the answers to your question, you may also want to read the tutorial on generics. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html

Answer (score 8):

You have put a Double in the Map.  Don't cast to String first.  This will work:

```
HashMap<String, Double> listMap = new HashMap<String, Double>();
mvalue = listMap.get("mvalue");
```

Your primitive double is being Autoboxed to a Double Object.  Use Generics to avoid the need to cast, which is the `<String, Double>` part.

Answer (score 3):

I guess your map will store many diferents types So I recomend <String, Object> generic

```
HashMap listMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
double mvalue =0.0;
listMap.put("mvalue",mvalue );
.
.
.
String mValueString = Double.toString((Double) listMap.get("mvalue"));
```

This will get you the double object, cast it to Double, and the convert into string in new variable.

Comment: Thanks. `HashMap listMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();` really solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

how about

```
mvalue = listMap.get("mvalue");
```

?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, make a HashMap with Class Types defined , like : `HashMap<String,Double>`

Secondly , this should work :

```
mvalue = Double.parseDouble(Double.toString(listMap.get("mvalue")));
```

Although, best way is :

```
mvalue = listMap.get("mvalue");
// provided defined HashMap is HashMap<String,Double>
```

Comment: if map stores double value then why to parse it? Here you are doing 2 unnecessary parsing. first double to string and then again string to double.

Comment: Sure, it works, but why go through the trouble of converting back and forth between String and Double when the value is already a Double?

Comment: yeah i knw..And i modified my answer to suit its needs..but i wanted to tell @yyy i 777 , how to go about in this situation..!!

Comment: The Map already holds a Double.  If mvalue needs to be a primitive then unboxing will do it.  Why on earth would you do the toString call, only to parse it as a Double ?

Answer (score 1):

If you introduce generics you will immeditely discover the probblem

```
Map<String, Double> listMap = new HashMap<String, Double>();
Double mvalue = listMap.get("mvalue");
```

The reason is that your map *does* return a `Double` and not a `String`, hence the error message.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
HashMap<String, Double> listMap = new HashMap<String, Double>();
Double mvalue = 0.0;
listMap.put("mvalue", mvalue);
mvalue = listMap.get("mvalue");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should looks like:

```
Map<String,Double> listMap = new HashMap<String,Double>();
double mvalue = 0.0;
listMap.put("mvalue", mvalue );
mvalue = Double.parseDouble( String.valueOf(listMap.get("mvalue")) );
```

Notice that if you need to retrieve a wrapper and not a primitive type, you can use on wrapper classes XXX.valueOf() instead of XXX.parseXXX() which returns a primitive.

Answer (score 0):

```
mvalue = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(listMap.get("mvalue")));
```